# How to re-position the salesforce login web view in iOS

Tags: ios, salesforce

I'm new in salesforce SDK, I'm trying to reposition the Salesforce login web view so the web view will not cover the status bar. I want to make it a bit lower (y-axis).

Heres the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Salesforce1 you cannot reposition login web view. You will see your changes only once you log in. You can modify your detailed and edit pages using compact layouts.

Regards,

Naveen

[autorabit](http://www.autorabit.com)